# Is it possible to use FFMPEG to generate F4V videos?

Tags: flash, video, ffmpeg, media

I need to generate a script that converts videos to F4V's for use with Flash Media Server 4.5...is this possible?  I have it converting files to MP4s and then swapping the extension. This works fine, but seems like a dirty work around.  I'd prefer to use a generate a true F4V. I've heard mixed things on whether or not ffmpeg truly supports F4Vs.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  Also, is there a doc guide on what file formats are allowed by FFMPEG?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that you can create h.264 mp4 files and then change the extension to .f4v - after which FMS should be able to handle it. I haven't tried this myself though.

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I am in the same boat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything I've read suggests that there is little to no difference between MP4 and flattened F4V video.  In my case, I'm stripping out the audio, remastering it and muxing it back with the original video.  We're still on FMS 3.5, but I'm having success with the following:

```
ffmpeg \
  -r 30000/1001 \         # Specifying video fps (29.97)
  -i orig.f4v \           # orig.f4v - h264 video, mp3 audio (recorded using FMS 3.2)
  -i new.wav \            # new.wav - remastered audio from orig.f4v
  -map 0:0 \              
  -map 1:0 \
  -vcodec copy \          # Preserving original h264 encoded video
  -acodec aac \           # Using experimental AAC encoder, could use libfaac if available
  -ab 96k \               # Matching audio bitrate to original bitrate
  -strict experimental \  # Necessary to use the experimental AAC encoder
  -async 1 \              
   new.f4v

#List of available formats
ffmpeg -formats

#List of available codecs
ffmpeg -codecs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i coup.mp4 -c copy -f mp4 out.f4v
```

According to FFmpeg source, `f4v` is treated the same as an `mp4`

```
if (!strchr(fname, ':') &&
    (!strcmp(fname + strlen(fname) - 4, ".f4v") ||
     !strcmp(fname + strlen(fname) - 4, ".mp4"))) {
    memcpy(rt->playpath, "mp4:", 5);
} else {
    rt->playpath[0] = 0;
}
```

## [source](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;hb=HEAD;f=libavformat/rtmpproto.c)

Comment: I too am interested in how to do this. I know how to create an `flv` using `ffmpeg`, but not an `f4v`. If you absolutely need the above information in order to give a full answer, let me try to give you what I can. ***Input container:*** `MOV - QuickTime`, ***Input video codec:*** `QuickTime Animation (RLE)`, ***Input audio codec:*** `AAC`, ***Desired output video codec:*** `H.264`, ***Desired output audio codec:*** `AAC`. I look forward to the answer!

Comment: Alas I got two errors using your above code: 1) ***track 0: could not find tag, codec not currently supported in container*** 2) ***Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?)*** Is that saying there's something wrong with the mp4 option?